# no type parameters for method flatMap

Tags: scala

I don't know why the following code can not compile, this is the error message:

> Error:(29, 7) no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: String => Option[B])Option[B] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (String => Some[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 <: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec })
>        --- because ---
>       argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
>        found   : String => Some[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 <: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec }
>        required: String => Option[?B]
>           a.flatMap(codecClassName => {
>             ^

and code

```
  def f(a: Option[String]): Unit = {
    a.flatMap(codecClassName => {
      val codecFactory = new CompressionCodecFactory(new Configuration())
      val codecClass = codecFactory.getCodecClassByName(codecClassName)
      if (codecClass == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown or not supported codec:" + codecClassName)
      }
      Some(codecClass)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related to the fact that getClass and classOf are not returning the exact same thing. See [Scala equivalent of Java java.lang.Class<T> Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135248/scala-equivalent-of-java-java-lang-classt-object) for more details.

Looking around for a workaround I came across [Scala Getting class type from string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402413/scala-getting-class-type-from-string-representation).

So how about:

```
val codecClass = Manifest.classType(codecFactory.getCodecClassByName(codecClassName))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I still could not understand why I can not use getClass, even it is different from classOf, but I didn't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. `flatMap` involves both `map` and `flatten`, so it may need more type annotations in some cases. The overall code works after annotation of the function parameter, i.e. `(codecClassName: String)`.

Note the other change -- that `flatMap` with an inner function returning an `Option` type is the same as a `map` if that function returns what's inside the Option (i.e. flattens the option) (see below).

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.{CompressionCodec, CompressionCodecFactory}
...
  def f(a: Option[String]): Option[Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]] = {
    a.map((codecClassName: String) => {
      val codecFactory = new CompressionCodecFactory(new Configuration())
      val codecClass   = codecFactory.getCodecClassByName(codecClassName)
      if (codecClass == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown or not supported codec:" + codecClassName)
      }
      codecClass
    })
  }
```

To show the relationship between flatMap and map as described above:

```
scala> val opt: Option[Int] = Some(1)
opt: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> opt.map((i: Int) => i + 1)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> val opt2: Option[Int] = None
opt2: Option[Int] = None

scala> opt.flatMap((i: Int) => Some(i + 1))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> opt2.map((i: Int) => i + 1)
res3: Option[Int] = None

scala> opt2.flatMap((i: Int) => Some(i + 1))
res2: Option[Int] = None
```